# How do you search all users for a package using conda cli?

Tags: python, conda

Using the `conda` CLI, how do you search for a package for all the users in `anaconda.org` ? Currently I just use the website. Is there a way to do it using the CLI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a search in the `binstar` tool, provided by Continuum. You can install it, **drumroll** from Binstar!

```
conda install -c binstar binstar
```

Then, for example, to find all the `opencv` packages in public conda channels:

```
binstar search -t conda opencv
```